# Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.5 -> check-update -> Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, redhat, rhel8

I want to update GCP Instance where Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.5 is installed. When I try 'sudo dnf check-update' I get an error:

> ```
> Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'rhui-codeready-builder-for-rhel-8-x86_64-rhui-debug-rpms': Cannot
> ```
>
> download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors
> were tried

If I try ' curl -I https://cds.rhel.updates.googlecloud.com ' I get response:

> ```
> HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
>
> curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
> ```

Do you have any suggestions how to make it work?

Comment: Is your system registered? `# subscription-manager list`
  Status:         Not Subscribed
  Status Details: Not covered by a valid subscription . `yum/dnf` will not work if your system is unregistered

Answer (score 1):

`Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'rhui-codeready-builder-for-rhel-8-x86_64-rhui-debug-rpms': Cannot`

The above error might have caused because of many reasons:

Network connectivity to the rhel repo
License issues
Temporary glitches

We can rule out network connectivity issues since you were able to crul the repo url. If you are using your own license check whether your license is active and if you are using google repos try to disable the repo and enable it again and then run the update command

dnf --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo="google-compute-engine" install google-rhui-client-rhel8

dnf update

If you are using any proxy in your gcp environment try to check that necessary [configs](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/failed-to-download-metadata-for-repo-repo_name/) are available.